# Amazon RDS: Why is Security Groups listed twice?

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, amazon-rds, security-groups

Via the AWS Management Console:

- I created an Elastic Beanstalk app configured with RDS.
- When I look at my Amazon RDS PostgreSQL DB instance details, I see Security Groups listed twice, with two different values. Why?

Both values say "( active )" at the end.

Clicking on the first value takes me to Security Groups on the RDS Dashboard, where it says:

> Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances. Go to the EC2 Console to view and manage your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see [AWS Documentation on Supported Platforms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-platforms.html) and [Using RDS in VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html).

Clicking on the second value takes me to Security Groups on the EC2 Dashboard, with the corresponding security group selected. I think this is the one the RDS instance is using, right? But then, why is the other one listed too?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a bug with AWS.

To fix it, I ran the commands below to [delete DB VPC security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html#Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.DeleteDBVPCGroups), as one somehow got created, perhaps by Elastic Beanstalk.

```
aws rds describe-db-security-groups
aws rds delete-db-security-group --db-security-group-name <value>
```

Comment: Hopefully you took a screenshot and reported the bug to AWS.